# can't find variable function declaration react native

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native

I get the error "variable uploadImageAsync cannot be found"

```js
uploadImageAsync = async (uri) => {
  console.log("In upload image asnyc!");
}
```

And this is where I call it from.

```js
_handleImagePicked = async pickerResult => {
let uploadResponse, uploadResult;

  this.setState({ uploading: true });

  if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
    uploadResponse = await uploadImageAsync(pickerResult.uri);
    uploadResult = await uploadResponse.json();
    this.setState({ image: uploadResult.location });
  }
    this.setState({ uploading: false });
};
```

How can I get around this?

So far I've tried:

```js
async function uploadImageAsync(uri) {
```

I've also tried:

```js
async uploadImageAsync(uri) {
```

Comment: should you not add a const before uploadImageAsync?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `uploadImageAsync` function defined in the same component, you need call `this.uploadImageAsync`.

Otherwise, you must `import` it from the other module

or define the function outside the component in the same file.